# How they got the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the following equations: $$1-\frac{\mu}{1+x_{1}-x_{2}^{2}} = 0 \\ -2 + \frac{2 \mu x_{2}}{1+x_{1}-x_{2}^{2}}-\frac{\mu}{x_2} = 0$$

Assume that $1+x_1-x_{2}^{2} \geq 0$ and $x_{2} \geq 0$. Solving for $x_2$ in terms of $\mu$ is just a matter of back substitution? In other words using the first equation to solve for $x_1$ in terms of $x_2$. Then substitute this into the second equation to get a quadratic in $x_2$?

Comment: You use the first equation to simplify the second, leading to a quadratic in $x_2$ and $\mu$ (no $x_1$s anymore); then the inequalities let you figure out which of the two values is $x_2$. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first equation we obtain
$$\begin{align*}
1 - \frac{\mu}{1+x_1-x_2^2} &= 0\\
1 &= \frac{\mu}{1+x_1-x_2^2}
\end{align*}$$

You can then simplify the second equation by noting that the second summand gives
$$\frac{2\mu x_2}{1+x_1-x_2^2} = \frac{\mu}{1+x_1-x_2^2}\left(2x_2\right) = 2x_2,$$
which means that the second equation is equivalent to
$$-2 + 2x_2 - \frac{\mu}{x_2} = 0$$
and we can solve this for $x_2$ in terms of $\mu$ by multiplying through by $x_2$ and solving the quadratic:
$$\begin{align*}
-2 + 2x_2 - \frac{\mu}{x_2} &= 0\\
-2x_2 + 2x_2^2 - \mu &= 0\\
x_2 &= \frac{2\pm\sqrt{4 + 8\mu}}{4}\\
&= \frac{2\pm 2\sqrt{1+2\mu}}{4}\\
&= \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+2\mu}}{2}.
\end{align*}$$
Since $\mu\gt 0$, $\sqrt{1+2\mu}\gt 1$, hence $1-\sqrt{1+2\mu}\lt 0$.  So we conclude that $x_2 = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{1+2\mu})$.